# Can you suggest me a way to store data of the weekly efforts in the database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I have to store data of the efforts spent by an individual everyday.
For that I have developed a small windows forms tool using C#, where users can open it and fill the efforts they have spent on a particular task, on the particular day.

This is the screenshot of the tool for better understanding.

[image]

User can click on "next" or "previous" buttons to go to the respective weeks and enter the efforts they have spent under that date.

I am using MS Access DB to store the data. And I have created only one column "Efforts" to store the efforts.

I am not sure how I can store the data on the DB, as user should be able to update the efforts in case of wrong entries done before.

It would be very helpful, if any of you can give your opinion on how to store the data, including the week and the date, so that user can also be able to update the data later.

Comment: Ok, may I ask why? Why does it have to be 1 column? Why not store record for each date and each user separately? So, 4 columns, (employee id, date, task id, effort) will be used in an efforts table. Employee ID, date and task id will become unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a table which lists the tasks.  This should at least have an ID and a Name.  Then you have another table for storing Efforts.  This should have its own ID, TaskID (which maps to Task.ID and should be ideally set with a foreign key constraint), Date and Effort.

Comment: See the second half of what I wrote - the Effort table should allow you to do that.